# how to display the errors in .catch coming from an api on frontend

Tags: laravel, reactjs, axios

I am building a project using **laravel** which is simple `api` i have built using passport and on the `frontend` i am using **react** everything works fine except that i can't catch the error messages in the .catch function i can see the errors in the network tab of my browser but i cant figure out how to display them.

here is my UserController

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only('name', 'email', 'password');
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
        ]);
   }
}
```

and this how i consume the api using axios:

```
export function signupUser({ name, email, password }) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/signup`, {name, email, password})
            .then(response => {

            dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });

            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access_token);

            browserHistory.push('/feature');
        })
        .catch((error) =>  {
            // console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the console log

[image]

and here is the response in the network tab of my browser

[image]

- If you have any question please let me know.
- Any help will be appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines of code.

```
.catch((error) =>  {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you @imran I have been debuggin this for more than hour.

Comment: @AmrAly Welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
.catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            // The request was made, but the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an 
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
      return error;
    });
```

Please check the below code

https://github.com/johibkhan2/react-redux-singlePageApp/blob/master/app/api/phone-api.js